# Inserting content within HEREDOC using Functions

Tags: php, jquery, dom

Been trying to go bout how to accomplish dividing content on view output.

I'm loading records from Mysql, inserting values into HEREDOC to then output to view.

I want to display only a certain amount of characters in a particular row within the HEREDOC, hide the rest from view on DOM.

[image]

I tried using a function like this within the HEREDOC to insert a "More" link after certain amount of characters.

I've tried a couple methods:

**1**

```
<<<EOT
<div id="$id_op">
    {substr_replace($contents, "More", 400)}
</div>

EOT;
```

**2**

```
<<<EOT
    <div id="$id_op">
        {${substr_replace($contents, "More", 400)}}
    </div>

EOT;
```

There might be other better methods to accomplish this. For now I want to load the record completely into dom but hide part of it until user have clicked a jQuery selector.

Any help / direction will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104516/calling-php-functions-within-heredoc-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions does not execute in HEREDOC. This will work

```
$div = substr_replace($contents, "More", 400);
$data = <<<EOT
<div id="$id_op">
    $div
</div>
EOT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Compute any variable content *before* starting the HEREDOC, then insert the variables into the string as you go.