# Execute php syntax within heredoc <<<END

Tags: php, heredoc

I want to execute a `php` syntax within a `html` code. My code is as follow :

```
return <<<END
<!-- Some HTML code -->
<header id="header">
    <?php include '../src/top.php'; ?>
    <!--LOGO bar / End-->
    <?php include '../src/nav.php'; ?>
</header>
<!-- Some HTML code -->
END;
```

But unfortunately, the php script have not been executed. I've used another syntax found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104516/calling-php-functions-within-heredoc-strings) :

```
return <<<END
<!-- Some HTML code -->
<header id="header">
    {include '../src/top.php';}
    <!--LOGO bar / End-->
    {php include '../src/nav.php';}
</header>
<!-- Some HTML code -->
END;
```

But none solve my problem. 
How can I fix this ?

Comment: You can't open php tags inside a HEREDOC. Anyway, that's a sign your mixing things too much

Comment: Any reason you're using heredoc AND `<?php ?>` tags? Do you *need* to use heredoc at all?