# PHP - valid variable names

Tags: php

In the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) on variables, we can read:

> *Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'*

So obviously when we try to run:

```
$0-a = 5;
echo $0-a;
```

we will get Parse error. This is quite obvious.

However when trying some things, what I found is that actually variables can contain any characters (or at least start with numbers and contain hyphens) when using such syntax:

```
${'0-a'} = 5;
echo ${'0-a'};
```

it works without any problems.

Also using variable variables like this:

```
$variable = '0-a';
$$variable = 5;
echo $$variable;
```

works without any problem.

So the question is - is that sentence I quote in manual is not true or maybe this what I showed is not real variable or maybe it's documented somewhere else in PHP manual?

I've verified it - and it seems to work both in PHP 5.6 and 7.1

Also the question is - is it safe to use such constructions? Based on manual it seems it shouldn't be possible at all.

Comment: Nice question. Why would somebody use those ugly variable names? However I guess the interpreter works correctly with them due to tolerance but as they do not work fully (e.g. in simple declaration) its not officially supported. Or can somebody state why it would be correct?

Comment: Sidenote; I made an edit to the question as to what the manual you had in mind. If it wasn't, you can do a rollback and use the actual URL for what you intended to use.

Comment: Who the heck voted this as "too broad"? I see so many HNQs for C and C++ stuff for seemingly similar construct questions that get answers in the magnitude of published research for explaining some amazing bit-flip optimization which compiler 12.4.23.0006 performs but 12.4.23.0005 did not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can literally choose *any* name for a variable. `"i"` and `"foo"` are obvious choices, but `""`, `"\n"`, and `"foo.bar"` are *also* valid. The reason? The PHP symbol table is just a dictionary: a string key of *zero or more bytes* maps to a structured value (called a [zval](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php)). Interestingly, there are *two* ways to access this symbol table: lexical variables and dynamic variables.

Lexical variables are what you read about in the ["variables"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) documentation. Lexical variables define the symbol table key during compilation (ie, while the engine is lexing and parsing the code). To keep this lexer simple, lexical variables start with a `$` sigil and must match the regex `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`. Keeping it simple this way means the parser doesn't have to figure out, for example, whether `$foo.bar` is a variable keyed by `"foo.bar"` or a variable `"foo"` string concatenated with a constant `bar`.

Now dynamic variables is where it gets interesting. Dynamic variables let you  access those more uncommon variable names. PHP calls these [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). (I'm not fond of that name, as their opposite is logically "constant variable", which is confusing. But I'll call them variable variables here on.) The basic usage goes like:

```
$a = 'b';
$b = 'SURPRISE!';
var_dump($$a, ${$a}); // both emit a surprise
```

Variable variables are parsed differently than lexical variables. Rather than defining the symbol table key at lexing time, the symbol table key is evaluated at *run time*. The logic goes like this: the PHP lexer sees the variable variable syntax (either `$$a` or more generally `${expression}`), the PHP parser defers evaluation of the expression until at run-time, then at run-time the engine uses the *result of the expression* to key into the symbol table. It's a little more work than lexical variables, but far more powerful.

Inside of `${}` you can have an expression that evaluates to *any byte sequence*. Empty string, null byte, all of it. Anything goes. That is handy, for example, in [heredocs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36202673/2908724). It's also handy for accessing remote variables as PHP variables. For example, JSON [allows any character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8676021/2908724) in a key name, and you might want to access those as straight variables (rather than array elements):

```
$decoded = json_decode('{ "foo.bar" : 1 }');
foreach ($decoded as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
}
var_dump(${'foo.bar'});
```

Using variable variables in this way is similar to using an array as a "symbol table", like `$array['foo.bar']`, but the variable variable approach is perfectly acceptable and slightly faster.

---

**Addendum**

By "slightly faster" we are talking so far to the right of the decimal point that they're practically indistinguishable. It's not until 10^8 symbol accesses that the difference exceeds 1 second in my tests.

```
Set array key: 0.000000119529
Set var-var:   0.000000101196
Increment array key: 0.000000159856
Increment var-var:   0.000000136778
```

The loss of clarity and convention is likely not worth it.

```
$N = 100000000;

$elapsed = -microtime(true);
$syms = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) { $syms['foo.bar'] = 1; }
printf("Set array key: %.12f\n", ($elapsed + microtime(true)) / $N);

$elapsed = -microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) { ${'foo.bar'} = 1; }
printf("Set var-var:   %.12f\n", ($elapsed + microtime(true)) / $N);

$elapsed = -microtime(true);
$syms['foo.bar'] = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) { $syms['foo.bar']++; }
printf("Increment array key: %.12f\n", ($elapsed + microtime(true)) / $N);

$elapsed = -microtime(true);
${'foo.bar'} = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) { ${'foo.bar'}++; }
printf("Increment var-var:   %.12f\n", ($elapsed + microtime(true)) / $N);
```

Comment: So it seems that Php manual is not completely true about variable names, right? Because what was written there is actually about tokenizer and not real variable names?

Comment: I just like to think of this as the PHP manual's way of ensuring that newcomers can't easily write horrendous variable names (and code) for future readers of the code base and once you are advanced enough to learn that this is possible then you choose not to do it for the aforementioned reason.

Comment: I second what @MonkeyZeus said. The variable page is meant as an introduction to the use of variables as a common way to manipulate data. While it's *technically* true that the tokenizer is limited to what constitutes a variable name, it's *irrelevant and distracting* to the discussion of variables. Later on in the variable variables chapter it could be mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen on php.net (spanish version) things like $función, $año * and so, always wanted to try, but never did. However, for some reason I wrote some vars like $1a ($1st), $2a, $3a... And it worked, no '${1a}' or stuff needed, but, Phpstorm is nagging me with warnings like 
"Expected: semicolon" and 
"Expression is not assignable: Constant reference".
So, after reading your experiences in this article, and to clean my editor from warnings and avoid possible future problems, I just changed everything to $a, $b, $c, etc.
Note: $ano (year) in spanish is anus, so nobody likes to use it